# Workaround for Grid.SharedSizeGroup in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, grid

There is no `Grid.SharedSizeGroup` in Silverlight 4. What is your workaround for this issue?

For example: I have a `DataTemplate` for `ListBox.ItemTemplate` consisting of a grid with two columns and I'd like to have the same width for both columns and the first column needs to have auto width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SharedSize Grid with Silverlight](http://die-rooter.de/ITworks/archives/27-SharedSize-Grid-with-Silverlight.html) - haven't tested it but looks usable.

Comment: Hint from one of the developers of the first link in this post: Our code currently does not support DataTemplates. We consider providing the source code for direct download in the blog, maybe someone can expand this missing feature and provide back the updated version to us for sharing via the blog...

Answer (score 3):

Vote for this feature here:

http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1454947-sharedsizegroup

and also here:

http://connectppe.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/518461/sharedsizegroup-should-be-available-in-silverlight

Answer (score 1):

Shared sizing is best implemented using element property bindings in Silverlight.  Just make all your shared sized elements bind to the width/height of another.

**EDIT:**
I put a quick example of what I mean together. I'm not sure what you mean by using star sizing when you said in the question you want auto sizing -

```
<Grid Height="400"
      Width="600"
      Background="Gray">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="parent"
            Content="CHANGE ME TO ADJUST THE COLUMN SIZE"
            Grid.Column="0"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Background="Red" />
    <Button Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=parent}"
            Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Background="Blue" />
    <Button Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=parent}"
            Grid.Column="2"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Background="Yellow" />
</Grid>
```

HTH

Comment: Can you elaborate? What if I want the controls to fill space or use grid stars?